# Page reload in ruby controller function

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

In my ruby application, i have a controller function to decrease the count of the product quantity in the cart.

## order_controller_decorator.rb:

```
def decrease
  quantity = change_quantity(-1)
  render json: { quantity: quantity, total:current_order.display_item_total }
end
```

In view file, the decrease button is called as below:

## _line.html.haml

```
 .quantity_changer
      = link_to decrease_order_path(line_item.id), method: :post, remote: true, class: 'cart-item-change minus' do
        %i.fa.fa-minus
```

Here,how can i make my page to reload after the decrease action.

I have tried adding

```
redirect_to :back
```

But it didn't work.

Please help me to solve this issue..

Comment: How do you call this function from the view ? You may not need to reload the full page, but just the html fragment that concerne the quantity.

Comment: @RenaudKern , In item.html.haml file ,                                                     `     .quantity_changer
      = link_to decrease_order_path(line_item.id), method: :post, 
         remote: true, class: 'cart-item-change minus' do
         %i.fa.fa-minus  `

Comment: @RenaudKern , I have updated my question with the view file

Comment: As the controller render json, the browser will not reload the page. What you try to do is Ajax. You can follow this tutorial to get inspired: https://coderwall.com/p/kqb3xq/rails-4-how-to-partials-ajax-dead-easy

Comment: IF you just want the page to reload then this shouldn't be a remote call and you can just re-render the the page just like every other page render works

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rails 5 there is a redirect method just for this purpose.
 `redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path,notice: "your notice here")`

Comment: I have tried the following method , but didn't work ... , Since the values are rendered as jSON , it is creating an internal server error..